# angular js : how to post two http post in one function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I would like to save the details of my candidate after assigning questionnaire and their details like first name, last name and so on. However, I am doing it in two parts in my web api.

This is my angular controller code.

```
MainApp.controller('CandidateController', ['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', '$filter', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $window, $http, $location, $routeParams, $filter, $mdDialog) {

    $scope.saveCandidate = function () {


        if ($scope.mailingSameAsPermanent ) {

            $scope.candidateData.MailingAddress.Address1 = "Same";
        }

        $http.post('api/Candidate/AddCandidate', JSON.stringify($scope.candidateData))
            .then(function () { $location.path("/candidate"); },
                    function () { $scope.message = "Save error"; })
        $http.post('api/Candidate/AssignQuestionnaire', 

JSON.stringify($scope.candidateData))
            .then(function () { $location.path("/candidate"); },
                        function () { $scope.message = "Save error"; })
        };
}]);
```

How do I post two http posts in one scope?

Comment: Not sure if you can assign two url posts in one http. If your above syntax is right then you should be doing fine

Comment: You can make it sequential first complete `AddCandidate` after that `AssignQuestionnaire` after completing both you can do your other operations.

Comment: But i need to compare the mailing address first then assign questionnaire & then add candidate,,

Comment: What do you mean by one scope?

Comment: @Chandermani can you see it's all under $scope.saveCandidate?

Comment: The call are inside one function `saveCandidate` not scope. The question is still vague.

Comment: @Chandermani sorry. hmm, do you have any idea if i can post two http posts in one function?